# Unable to load accounts with Google Analytics Api

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm having issues trying to retrive accounts list with google analytics API.
I'm connecting without problems with Oauth2 granting right permission to my App.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$client->setAuthConfig('path/to/credentials.json');
$client->addScope(array(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS));
$client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());
...
```

I'm also able to do some queries with code like the following:

```
$service = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client); 
$dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
$dateRange->setStartDate("2019-01-01");
$dateRange->setEndDate("2019-06-30");
// Create the Metrics objects.
$sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
$sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
$sessions->setAlias("ga:sessions");
...
```

When I try to retrive accounts list I receive an error 500

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
$accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();
$items = $accounts->getItems();
print_r($accounts);
```

If I do instead

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
var_dump($analytics->management_accounts);
```

I'm able to see a json output where no listManagementAccounts is viewable and no account id is available.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out deleting and creating again API credentials in Google Console.
Code was fine.